# Custom iphone Camera Settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

What is the AVFoundation equivalent for this UIImagePicker enabled method? My app uses AVFoundation and I want to nix UIImagePicker entirley. This method comes after a UIImagePicker class is set up in the program. It sets a hypothetical image a user takes (physically using the iPhone camera interface) to an IBOutlet named photo, declared earlier in app. excerpt from http://www.raywenderlich.com/13541/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-22 (download at bottom)

```
#pragma mark - Image picker delegate methods
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
// Resize the image from the camera
UIImage *scaledImage = [image resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill bounds:CGSizeMake(photo.frame.size.width, photo.frame.size.height) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];
// Crop the image to a square (yikes, fancy!)
UIImage *croppedImage = [scaledImage croppedImage:CGRectMake((scaledImage.size.width -photo.frame.size.width)/2, (scaledImage.size.height -photo.frame.size.height)/2, photo.frame.size.width, photo.frame.size.height)];
// Show the photo on the screen
photo.image = croppedImage;
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}



 //Successful avcam snap i want to use. Uses AVFoundation
 - (IBAction)snapStillImage:(id)sender
{
dispatch_async([self sessionQueue], ^{
    // Update the orientation on the still image output video connection before capturing.
    [[[self stillImageOutput] connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] setVideoOrientation:[[(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[[self previewView] layer] connection] videoOrientation]];
    // Flash set to Auto for Still Capture
    [PhotoScreen setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeAuto forDevice:[[self videoDeviceInput] device]];
    // Capture a still image.
    [[self stillImageOutput] captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:[[self stillImageOutput] connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
        if (imageDataSampleBuffer)
        {
            NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
            [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[image imageOrientation] completionBlock:nil];
            //

        }
    }];
});
}
```

Note: the AVCam method is part of an AVSession which apples describes as the class to coordinate all data flow for media capture using AVFoundation. The full official program from Apple for AVCam is here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html

I happened to stumble upon this excerpt located in AVCamViewController. I noticed it looks a lot like the method in question. Can someone help verify its scalability?

```
#pragma mark File Output Delegate
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error
{
if (error)
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
[self setLockInterfaceRotation:NO];
// Note the backgroundRecordingID for use in the ALAssetsLibrary completion handler to end the background task associated with this recording. This allows a new recording to be started, associated with a new UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier, once the movie file output's -isRecording is back to NO — which happens sometime after this method returns.
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundRecordingID = [self backgroundRecordingID];
[self setBackgroundRecordingID:UIBackgroundTaskInvalid];
[[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:outputFileURL error:nil];
    if (backgroundRecordingID != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundRecordingID];
}];
}
```

Comment: what's the warning? Can you share the message?

Comment: the method I tried is highlighted in that picture. I will rebuild the project to get a more current snapshot of the warnings. Any ideas still appreciated. thanks.

Comment: are you including all the required framework?

Comment: Sure. I simply copied the IBAction for taking a picture using apples AVFoundation free source code called AVcam seen here.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html I changed it to void and programmed it to go off in view didload. I want that picture to be used instead of the image picker instance

Comment: Apple is very upfront in describing the AVFoundation classes for camera support. So far the results seem to scale similarly minus a few keywords here and there...do you have any ideas for scaling the original method? I will try recompiling for a more accurate update...

Comment: because you're getting linker error and all references are related to iOS framework. So, I'm wondering something wrong in the framework/library you included in the linking. To resize image, as you are calling [image resizedImageWithContentMode ..], I expect you are using 3rd-party library or category. Make sure those libs/categories are included in your build.

Comment: Still recompiling...in the mean time keep in mind the application apple provides has all the necessary classes and instances so its just a matter of plugging in the right classes

Comment: yes, good eye. `image resizedWithContentMode` was declared in a supporting .h .m file. ***spoiler alert*** the original code is an excerpt from this app if you wanted to take a closer look. The snippet you mentioned is in the supporting files folder>UIImageResize etc...  http://www.raywenderlich.com/13541/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-22

Comment: Anyone know what AVFoundation classes to update the `imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` method with?

Comment: @kilogen9 you were absolutely right. I didn't add avfoundation manually from the build settings tab and instead added #imports...after added avfoundation the app finally compiled and those 13 errors dissapeared

Comment: now, any ideas for updating the method? Ill try some things out on my end

Comment: what 'method' are you referring to ?

Comment: `-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info ` is called after a user takes a physical picture. It sets the UIImagePicker picture the user takes to an IBOutlet named photo. It is just a helper method but it pretty much sets up the entire foundation of the app because it ultimately saves the image to where it is used later in son. I can add the entire methodology for the UIImagePicker instantiation if it'd be more helpful.

Comment: Otherwise I am still looking to make that code reflect the AVFoundation snapStillImage output. In other words want create the `IBOutlet UIImageView*photo` (seen in the first method as photo) using AVCam instances. I don't want to use UIImagePicker at all.

Comment: UIImgePicker and AVFoundation are two different techniques. If you use UIImagePicker, you need to set the delegate so that the delegate method is being called. Of course, you need to include the UIKit in the build.

Comment: Since the snapStillImage method is already in place (thanks to your help) I think this should be relatively easy ?

Comment: Yes, I set the viewcontroller using these methods to a <AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate>

Comment: Still need help in taking an image from snapStillImage and setting it to fit that method post take...Ill try some things.